# How to list files and folders recursively and separately with Boost and C++

Tags: c++, boost

In the boost documentation I found the code to list a directory files AND folders (but not recursively :( ), but I don't know how to do to generate only the list of all files, even those that are in the sub directories (recursively) OR the list of all folders (recursively too).

Comment: You need a recursive directory iterator, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem; 

#include <iostream>

int main() {

    for (auto& entry : boost::make_iterator_range(fs::recursive_directory_iterator("."), {}))
    {
        if (fs::is_regular_file(entry))
            std::cout << entry.path() << "\n";
    }

}
```

Prints e.g.

```
"./odata/marshal/json_light_test.cpp"
"./odata/marshal/core_test.cpp"
"./odata/marshal/json_verbose_test.cpp"
"./odata/edm/example_test.cpp"
"./odata/edm/builtin_test.cpp"
"./misc/naive_ptr_tests.cpp"
"./json/generic_visitor_tests.cpp"
"./json/json_tests.cpp"
"./azure/storage/test_service_definitions.hpp"
"./azure/storage/blob_tests.cpp"
"./azure/storage/table_tests.cpp"
```

Comment: Hi sehe, under VS2010 "entry :" is underlined in red and the message is "impossible to determine auto type, initializer is demanded" (translation to french sorry)

Comment: Then adapt to your version of the compiler. C++11 is quite old by now: `for (fs::recursive_directory_iterator b("."), e; b!=e; ++b)`

Comment: Thank you and how I change : if (fs::is_regular_file(entry))
            std::cout << entry.path() << "\n";

Comment: @Aminos If you have to ask that, you should read a book. It's simple iterators. You should really know this, or at least ask a separate question. ***[Voilà](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/617e13bf7284c13b)***

Comment: sorry sehe, I know iterators (from the STL) but I'm not very familiar with boost

Comment: Iterators are purposely shallow contracts: so whether they come from the standard library, the past (STL) or from the dark side: they're all iterators. [original Iterator concept from SGI STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html)

Comment: and to seperate files and folder, I can use is_regular_file or is_directory. Thank you

Comment: @Aminos and the rest of the documentation: [is_directory,
      is_empty,
      is_other,
      is_regular_file,
      is_symlink](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html) and perhaps [`b->status().type()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#file_type)